# Update column +1

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update my database when a page is visited.

Here is my code

```
        <?php

            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
    if (!$con) 
  {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

    mysql_select_db("xxx", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");

    $id=$_GET["q"];

    $sql="UPDATE audit SET lks =lks+1 WHERE id='$id'" or die(mysql_error());

    ?>
```

The database does not update at all?

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: try `"UPDATE audit SET lks =lks+1 WHERE id=" . $id` and execute the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not actually executing the query:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
if (!$con) 
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xxx", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");

$id=$_GET["q"];

$sql="UPDATE audit SET lks =lks+1 WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never query the sql statement.

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

And I wouldn't suggest using the mysql_* library, it's deprecated and isn't as secure as something like PDO or mysqli